# Excel VBA Editor - Space bar not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Our office has recently switched over to Windows 10. Inexplicably Space bar now functions sporadically in the VBA Editor. Sometimes I can get it to work again by restarting the editor, or typing in a cell in Excel, but other times it just refuses to produce a space character at all.

It almost seems like the space character is being typed and then removed very rapidly, I am at a total loss.

Edit1: Version 1084 - VBA Retail: 7.1.1084

Spacebar continues to work normally in other applications, and I am not convinced it is stuck in a non-modal state, if I understand the term.

Comment: What version of the editor are you using and does the space bar work in other applications?

Comment: Version 1084 - VBA Retail: 7.1.1084 and yes, yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  I was advised to switch off autosave (which required me to firstly save the workbook as a macro-enabled xlsm file).  This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! I usually switch this off to maintain some sort of version control, I never considered the feature a potential suspect, that could well be what it was...